# How to send mongodb data async from inner functions to outside callback function from a for loop?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, for-loop, callback

NEW POST:

Here is the sample of the working async code without a db.
The problem is, if i replace the vars (data1_nodb,...) with the db.collection.find();
function, all needed db vars received at the end and the for() loop ends not
correct. I hope that explains my problem a bit better. OA

```
        var calc = new Array();
        function mach1(callback){               
                    
                            error_buy = 0;                                                  
                            
                            // some vars                            
                            
                            for(var x_c99 = 0; x_c99 < array_temp_check0.length;x_c99++){
                                
                                // some vars                        
                                    
                                    calc[x_c99] = new Array();                                      
                                    calc[x_c99][0]= new Array();    
                                    
                                    calc[x_c99][0][0] = "dummy1";
                                    calc[x_c99][0][1] = "dummy2";
                                    calc[x_c99][0][2] = "dummy3";
                                    calc[x_c99][0][3] = "dummy4";
                                    calc[x_c99][0][4] = "dummy5";
                                    
                                    function start_query(callback) {

                                            data1_nodb = "data1";
                                            data2_nodb = "data2";
                                            data3_nodb = "data3";
                                            data4_nodb = "data4";

                                            
                                            calc[x_c99][0][0] = data1_nodb;
                                            calc[x_c99][0][1] = data2_nodb;
                                            calc[x_c99][0][2] = data3_nodb;
                                                        
                                        
                                            callback(data1_nodb,data2_nodb,etc..);
                                            
                                    }
                                        
                                            start_query(function() {
                                                
                                                console.log("start_query OK!"); 
                                                
                                                function start_query2(callback) {
                                                                    
                                                data4_nodb = "data5";
                                                data5_nodb = "data6";
                                                data6_nodb = "data7";
                                                
                                                
                                                calc[x_c99][0][3] = data4_nodb;
                                                calc[x_c99][0][4] = data5_nodb;
                                                    
                                                callback(data5_nodb,data6_nodb,etc..);
                                                
                                            }                                           
                                            
                                            start_query2(function() {
                                                
                                                console.log("start_query2 OK!");    
                                                
                                                    function start_query3(callback) {
                                                        
                                                            
                                                        for(...){
                                                            
                                                                // do something
                                                            }
                                                        
                                                            callback(vars...);                                              
                                                        }
                                            
                                                start_query3(function() {
                                                    console.log("start_query3 OK!");    
                                                });
                                            
                                            });
                                        }); 
                                }
                            
                            callback(calc); 
                
                    };
                    
                    
                    function mach2(callback){
                                    
                        mach1(function() {
                            
                            console.log("mach1 OK!");
                
                            for(...){                                                                                               
                            // do something                                                         
                            }   
                                                
                        });         
    
                        callback(calc,error_buy);
                        
                    };                          
                        
                    mach2(function() {
                    console.log("mach2 OK 2!");                                         
                    });
```

OLD POST:

i try to read data from the mongodb and send them back with a callback to the next
function, that needs the infos from the db to proceed.

Without the mongodb read functions it works perfect but now i dont know how
i can send the db vars out of the two inner functions to the first callback function.

Hope someone can help me...
Thanks

> var error = 0; var var1  = "yessir";
>
> function start_query(callback) {
>
> var db_name = "db1";

```
db[db_name].find({name:var1},{data1:1, data2:1, data3:1, data4:1}, function(err, data_catch,callback) {
    
    if( err || !data_catch ) {
        console.log("Problem finding data_catch:" + err);
    
    } else {
        
        data_catch.forEach( function(data_catch_finder,callback) {
        
            data1_db = data_catch_finder.data1;
            data2_db = data_catch_finder.data2;
            data3_db = data_catch_finder.data3;
            data4_db = data_catch_finder.data4;
                                                            
            if(data1_db == "" || data2_db == "" || data3_db == "" || data4_db == ""){error = 1; console.log("Error: data_catch_finder");}
             
             callback(data1_db, data2_db, data3_db, data4_db, error);
     
        }); 
      
    }
});
        
        
    callback(data1, data2, data3, data4, error);
        
}
             
//########################################################################
 
 start_query(function() {
     
     function start_query2(callback) {
         
         console.log("DATA1 from callback:" + data1_db);
         console.log("DATA2 from callback:" + data2_db);
         console.log("DATA3 from callback:" + data3_db);
         console.log("DATA4 from callback:" + data4_db);
         
         var var_no_db = "testing";
         
         //do something else and callback
         
         callback(var_no_db);
         
     }
     
     
     start_query2(function() {
         
         console.log("Var from callback start_query2:" + var_no_db);
         console.log("The end");
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

your callback signature are issuing `callback` as a parameter.

As far as I can understand your code, you need to keep reference of the first callback, the one you receive here: `function start_query(callback)`.

In every callback function you made the mistake to bind the variable name `callback` to the parameter from the mongo driver (a simple `undefined` i think).

You can fix it removing every reference of `callback` from the signature of your inner functions.

a simple example:

```
function async (cb) {
  // params: Error, data
  cb(null, 'moo');
}

function foo(callback) {
  async(function(err, data, callback){
    console.log(callback); // undefined
  });

  console.log(callback); // Moo
}

foo('Moo');
```

Take a look at [Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html) to better understand the JS context switching;

---

*edit*

The only way to wait the results of an async function is recall the first callback inside the last nested callback.

```
function ugly_nested (callback) {
  dbquery('...', function(err, data_01) {
    if (!! err) return callback(err);

    dbquery('...', function(err, data_02) {
      if (!! err) return callback(err);

      dbquery('...', function(err, data_03) {
        if (!! err) return callback(err);

        callback(null, data_01, data_02, data_03);
      });
    });
  });
}

ugly_nested(function(err, data01, data02, data03) {
  if (!! err) throw err;

  manage_data(data01, data02, data03);
});
```

The `FOR` loop is synchronous, but, the database calls are asynchronous, so, the for loop will end before the database returns his results. If you really need that for loop you can try out one of the nice [flow control libraries](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-async-flow) [out](https://github.com/creationix/step) [there](https://github.com/caolan/async)

Comment: Thanx! I post an example of the working code, without db. Hope that is better to understand. OA